# <label> on checkboxes: is there a reason why more websites don't use it?

Tags: html, usability, label

I always try to do the following:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" /> Some text</label>
```

or

```
<label for="idOfField"><input type="checkbox" id="idOfField" /> Some text</label>
```

My question is related to the label tag, specifically on a checkbox.

Most websites (I would say >40%) don't use the `<label>` tag.

Is there a reason for this? Is there a problem in a browser or some other issue?

**Note:** Incase people don't know about the `<label>` tag, it has a number of advantages:

- checkboxes & radios: you can click on the text as well as the checkbox to check the checkbox (as well as focus I believe):  Blah blah blah
- other inputs: if you click the text, it will focus the input (textarea, text, file) (this functionality isn't as useful as checkboxes & radios)

**Note 2:** Some people have mentioned that example #2 is more correct than #1 (above), but according to the documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1), either is correct

Comment: It's for accessibility and Eneki's answer (with the for attribute) is the more correct form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's probably more a factor that people don't know about the <label> tag. I didn't, until this post.

Comment: It's a shame this tag isn't more popular. I've even seen broken javascript trying to emulate its behavior :/

Comment: I evangelize the merits of the <label> tag.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that label is often an unknown tag.
I use it in the form

```
<label for="chk1">Some text</label><input id="chk1" type="checkbox"/>
```

The for attribute let the user click on the label also to select the checkbox with the corresponding id (not name) and not being annidate I can better control the layout with CSS.

I will try your solution, though

Comment: As far as I've experienced and in the docs, you can use it either way. The for attribute is not needed if the field is within the <label>

Answer (score 5):

There is no downside to using `<label>` that I know of. I 've used it a lot in the past few years.

There are actually 3 ways you can set a label, the first two correspond with the ones you gave in your question:

```
<label for="xa">XA: <input type="text" id="xa" /></label><br />
<label for="xb">XB:</label> <input type="text" id="xb" /><br />
<label>XC: <input type="text" id="xc" /></label>
```

All 3 of the above work in FF3 and IE7. I remember that for some reason I mentally marked the last two as "to be avoided, only partially work" though. Therefore I 'd bet good money that only the first one works in IE6.

To clarify: the "best" way to do it is my example #1, your example #2.

Comment: All these examples work in IE6. I'd say, the last two work 100%, the first one tries to be explicit twice, say 200% ;)

Answer (score 4):

Some older browsers don't interpret the **for** attribute, and instead require the form element to be nested within the **label** tag.

Comment: Would you care to back up with a link? (I'd like to know more)

Comment: Which ones? I know only that IE is broken, it the opposite way. It only supports `for`.

Answer (score 3):

The developer working on the site didn't know the `<label>` tag existed.

Comment: What do you mean? The only checkbox I see is the "community wiki" which has a label on it?

Comment: @Darryl, not sure what you're saying. I meant "developer" and "site" in general; not SO. I don't see how "community wiki" has anything to do with anything.

Comment: @BQ, my apologies, I thought you meant SO.

Answer (score 2):

Most web sites were made by people who only do what it takes to get the site to work like they think it should.  Process flow is:

1. Take a stab at it.
2. Load it in browser, and see what's wrong.
3. Search google for the fixes.
4. Repeat.

Since most of these people never try to focus any inputs without using the mouse, the problem never becomes evident.

Answer (score 2):

The advantages are obvious but I don't think most know about it because label seems to convey nothing concrete.  You can obviously see the advantage of using a strong tag because it makes the text look bold but label tag? You wouldn't notice anything different.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an underhyped tag that should get more attention. While you're at it (improving accessibility), don't forget the tabindex property.